# ruby on rails : how use xmlrpc/client for remote server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-rpc

I am using `xmlrpc/client` to work with remote xml-rpc server. I have searched a lot to find something useful, yet failed. The following code for establishing connection is correct?

```
require 'xmlrpc/client'
def init
    parameters = {
        host: "http://x.x.x.x",
        port: "1235",
        user: "x",
        password: "x"
    }
    connection = XMLRPC::Client.new_from_hash(parameters)
    x = connection.call("user.getUserInfo", :normal_username =>"x")

end
```

What kind of response should i expect if things go fine? I get `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known` when run code.

Comment: Haven't you tried to run the code?

Comment: Well, if you are searching for the host `x.x.x.x` you will hardly find it, you should use the real address of the host...

Comment: that works with php code, so i think something is wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to check:

- Have you tried using the `new` or `new2` or other similar methods instead of `new_from_hash` ? [Documentation here.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/xmlrpc/README_txt.html)
- Check that endpoint URL is correct. Often XMLRPC servers tend to append an `api/xmlrpc`.
- Check that the method exists.

Perhaps you can paste your PHP code as well here so that we can take a look at whether you have translated the code to Ruby correctly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have already tested all methods for connection, and the problem was http before ip.

Answer (score 0):

I put this problem solution here, maybe help someone out. Remove http before ip and put code like following:

```
connection = XMLRPC::Client.new('x.x.x.x', '/', 1235)
```